# Access django context variable from parent template

Tags: python, django

I can't set a django template variable from inside a children, any ideas what's wrong?

In my views.py:

```
return { 'header_title' : 'my text' }
```

base.html:

```
{{ header_title }}
```

main.html:

```
{{ extends "base.html" }}
```

details.html:

```
{{ extends "main.html" }}
```

That is not working. Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just return a dict from a view. A view must return an `HttpResponse` object. Try instead:

Django 1.3+ [render](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#render)

```
return render(request, 'main.html', { 'header_title': 'my text' })
```

Django <1.3 [render-to-response](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#render-to-response)

```
return render_to_response('main.html', { 'header_title': 'my_text' }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution could be to put in your base.html

```
<block title><endblock>
```

and in the chilren templates:

```
<block title>{{ header title}}<endblock>
```